# Smoothly predicting the location of the mouse cursor in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a rectangle on a canvas around the mouse cursor that smoothly follows the cursor. Unfortunately, the mousemoved event doesn't fire quickly enough, and the drawing constantly trails behind it. So I'm assuming I need to predict where the mouse is, and draw the rectangle at that point. I'm trying to write a simple library to abstract that away, but it's not tracking as closely as I'd like for fast movements (in fact, fast movements are jittery). For slow movements, it tracks fairly well, and better than the simple solution of using the raw mouse coordinates.

The basic idea is that mousemove updates a couple of external variables with the current position of the mouse. A requestAnimationFrame loop (the Watcher function) tracks these variables and their previous values over time to calculate the speed the mouse is moving at (in the x axis). When the PredictX function is called, it returns the current x position, plus the last change in x multiplied by the speed. A different reqeustAnimationFrame loop moves the rectangle based on the predicted x value.

```
var MouseLerp = (function () {
    var MOUSELERP = {};
    var current_x = 0;
    var last_x = 0;
    var dX = 0;
    var last_time = 0;
    var x_speed = 0;

    var FPS = 60;

    function Watcher(time) {
        var dT = time - last_time
        if (dT > (1000 / FPS)) {
            dX = last_x - current_x;
            last_x = current_x;
            x_speed = dX / dT

            last_time = time;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(Watcher);
    }

    MOUSELERP.PredictX = function () {
        return Math.floor((dX * x_speed) + current_x);
    }

    MOUSELERP.Test = function () {
        var target_element = $(".container")
        target_element.append('<canvas width="500" height="500" id="basecanvas"></canvas>');
        var base_ctx = document.getElementById("basecanvas").getContext("2d");

        var offset = target_element.offset()
        var offset_x = offset.left;
        var offset_y = offset.top;

        var WIDTH = $(window).width();
        var HEIGHT = $(window).height();

        var FPS = 60;

        var t1 = 0;

        function updateRect(time) {

            var dT = time - t1
            if (dT > (1000 / FPS)) {
                base_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
                base_ctx.beginPath();
                base_ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
                base_ctx.lineWidth = 2;

                base_ctx.rect(MOUSELERP.PredictX(), 100, 100, 100)
                base_ctx.stroke();
                t1 = time;
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(updateRect)
        }
        updateRect();

        $(target_element).mousemove(function (event) {
            current_x = event.pageX - offset_x;
        });

        requestAnimationFrame(Watcher);
    }
    MOUSELERP.Test()
    return MOUSELERP;
}())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a jsfiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/p8Lr224p/

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mouse pointer will always be quicker than drawing, so your best bet is not to give the user's eye a reason to perceive latency. So, turn off the mouse cursor while the user is drawing. Draw a rectangle at the mouse position to visually act as the mouse cursor.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

var mouseX=0;
var mouseY=0;

canvas.style.cursor="none";

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

function handleMouseMove(e){
  ctx.clearRect(mouseX-1,mouseY-1,9,9);
  mouseX=e.clientX-offsetX;
  mouseY=e.clientY-offsetY;
  ctx.fillRect(mouseX,mouseY,8,8);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Less 'lagging' when mouse is invisible & canvas draws cursor.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

,

Comment: Rats, I was really hoping there was a clever way to predict the mouse location.